# returning column names in a query in sql

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I have a query that looks something like this:

```
select * 
from resident 
where Resident_Sex is null or Resident_Date_Of_Birth is null or race_code is null.
```

not always is it only checking if 3 columns are null, it may have more. 
I want to know if there is a way, instead of selecting * from this table, to select lets say the resident id and the column name that he is missing.

for example, it should return

```
resident_id column_name
----------- ------------
aaaaaaa     resident_sex
bbbbbbb     resident_sex
bbbbbbb     race_code   
ccccccc     resident_date_of_birth
```

instead of returning

```
 resident_id resident_sex race_code   Resident_date_of_birth
 ----------- ------------ ----------- -----------------------
 aaaaaaa     null         158         1995-02-18 00:00:00.000
 bbbbbbb     null         null        1928-07-15 00:00:00.000
 ccccccc     F            12          null
```

Obviously there are alot more rows and columns in the table so I cannot do any case or if statements...

I hope I made myself clear... 
thank you in advance!

Comment: try using CASE WHEN like SELECT * from table CASSE WHEN resident_id = null, etc,.

Comment: can you elaborate a little more? I dont really understand what you are saying..

Answer (score 1):

You can unpivot your table using a series of `UNION ALL` operations. Then simply select every row that contains a `NULL`-valued column:

```
SELECT resident_id, column_name
FROM (
  SELECT resident_id, 'resident_sex' AS column_name
  FROM mytable
  WHERE resident_sex IS NULL

  UNION ALL

  SELECT resident_id, 'race_code'
  FROM mytable
  WHERE race_code IS NULL

  UNION ALL

  SELECT resident_id, 'Resident_date_of_birth'
  FROM mytable
  WHERE Resident_date_of_birth IS NULL) AS t
```

Comment: this would be a good idea if there were only 3 columns, but I am working with many more columns, can be over 50... I wanted to know if there was any other way without doing each column separately...

Comment: There is no other way I'm afraid using static SQL. You can try using prepared statements.

Comment: @programmingGirl Have a look [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15507683/how-to-select-column-names-dynamically-in-mysql).