# mysql: failed to embed select into select

Tags: mysql

I created a database for problem set with 6 column(`problemId`, `a` ,`b` ,`c` ,`d`
, `rightAnswer`), where `a`,`b`,`c`,`d` stores the details of each option and `rightAnswer` stores the index of right answer such as a, b, c, d.
Now I want to extract the index of right answer in `rightAnswer` (for example, a )and then select a from the table.
Here is my code:

```
SELECT (SELECT rightAnswer FROM table WHERE problemId=1) FROM table WHERE problemId=1
```

But it didn't work.

Comment: select requires a column name. You have placed a table result in place of it

Comment: "it didn't work" isn't very descriptive of the behavior you observe. If problemid is unique in the table (or, if the value 1 occurs in problemid on only one row), we would expect the query to return the value stored in the `rightanswer` column.  @AksheyBhat: MySQL expects a list of *expressions* following the SELECT keyword. Yes, a column name is an example of an expression, but we can also include more complex  expressions, including a scalar subquery (returning one column and at most one row.)

Comment: it just did not return the content in a column

Comment: Look at this if it can help you [How to select column names dynamically in mySQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15507683/how-to-select-column-names-dynamically-in-mysql)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a CASE expression ...

```
 SELECT CASE t.rightanswer 
          WHEN 'a' THEN t.a
          WHEN 'b' THEN t.b
          WHEN 'c' THEN t.c
          WHEN 'd' THEN t.d
          ELSE NULL
        END AS rightanswer_val
   FROM mytable t
  WHERE t.problemid = 1
```

That would serve to "decode" the value stored in the `rightanswer` column, and return the value stored in the corresponding column.

---

If you have some unfathomable need to "embed a select in a select" (as the title of your question suggests), it's possible to do that, though that's not needed for solving this problem.

In SQL, references to *identifiers* must appear in the text of a SQL statement. Values for identifiers (column names, table names, function names, etc.) cannot be generated dynamically by the execution of the statement. If you want to return the value from a column named `col`, then the name of that column `col` must appear in the actual SQL text.

Answer (score 0):

You can use dynamic query for this.

```
SET @col_name:= (SELECT rightAnswer FROM `table` WHERE problemId=1);
SET @sql:=CONCAT_WS(' ','SELECT ',@col_name,' FROM `table` WHERE problemId=1');
PREPARE dynamic_statement FROM @sql;
EXECUTE dynamic_statement;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE dynamic_statement;
```

Comment: There's no need to manufacture a tornado to blow out a match.