# Updating data between 2 Schemas MYSQL 5.7

Tags: sql, mysql, mysql-5.7

I am stuck and can use a pointer or two.
I have data in multiple tables in Schema A
There may (or may not) be additional fields in an update (not important for the moment).
I want to copy the data in Schema A into Schema B, but change the prefix on every table.

I can create Schema B with the data structure in Schema A and change the table prefixes using  CREATE TABLE ... SELECT * from
That works
The sticking point is UPDATE.  How do I update the information in Schema B with the data from Schema C ?
A and C are identical, C has the more recent information.
My question:  100 tables, how to do a batch update of all records using the information in Schema C ?
There are no keys

Thanks.  Constructive suggestions cheerfully accepted.

CREATE TABLE gets me part way there.
Need Update Table

Comment: MySQL 5.7 is reaching end of life in two months. Time to upgrade to MySQL 8.x.

Answer (score 1):

It is basically the same as any other `UPDATE`, only you add the schema before the tables and join them

```
UPDATE B.table1 t1
JOIN C.t2 t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
SET t1.mycolumn = t2.mycolumn, t1.mycolumn2 = t2.mycolumn2
```

Comment: An important point to consider if there is a replication. The schema selected should be the one in which the update will take place, because in statement format (I'm not sure for ROW or MIX ) it will break the replication. In your example OP should run `use schemaB;` before running the update

Comment: no the schema with table name is unique on thee server, so there is no need to use `USE`

Comment: So far so good, except ...
Is there a way to make this generic for a batch update?

SET t1.mycolumn = t2.mycolumn, t1.mycolumn2 = t2.mycolumn2

Can this be SET t1.* = t2.*
 or ?????

Comment: No you have to write every column down, or you build it from information schema see https://stackoverflow.com/a/15532584/5193536